# Show DialogFragment in navBackStackEntry observer result of another DialogFragment using NavigationComponent

Tags: java, android, android-dialogfragment, android-architecture-navigation

This is `onViewCreated` of My Fragment:

```
@Override
public void onViewCreated(@NonNull View view, @Nullable @org.jetbrains.annotations.Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);

    NavHostFragment navHostFragment = (NavHostFragment) requireActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.container);

    binding.button.setOnClickListener(v -> {
        if (navHostFragment != null) {
            NavController navController0 = navHostFragment.getNavController();

            navController0.navigate(MyFragmentDirections.actionMyFragmentToMessageDialog(
                    false,
                    R.drawable.ic_success,
                    "My Message 1",
                    R.string.yes,
                    R.string.no,
                    R.drawable.circle_yellow
            ));
        }
    });

    if (navHostFragment != null) {
        NavController navController1 = navHostFragment.getNavController();
        NavBackStackEntry navBackStackEntry = navController1.getCurrentBackStackEntry();
        if (navBackStackEntry != null) {
            SavedStateHandle savedStateHandle = navBackStackEntry.getSavedStateHandle();
            MutableLiveData<String> liveData = savedStateHandle.getLiveData(Const.DIALOG_BTN_DATA);
            liveData.observe(getViewLifecycleOwner(), btnData -> {
                //            savedStateHandle.remove(Const.DIALOG_BTN_DATA);

                if (btnData.equals("btn_right")) {
                    Log.i(TAG, "Dialog Btn Clicked -----> btn_right");
                    NavController navController2 = navHostFragment.getNavController();
                    navController2.navigate(MyFragmentDirections.actionMyFragmentToMessageDialog(
                            false,
                            R.drawable.ic_success,
                            "My Message 2",
                            R.string.yes,
                            R.string.no,
                            R.drawable.circle_red
                    ));

                } else {
                    // Do Some Stuff
                }
            });
        }
    }
}
```

And this is the button `onClickListener` of Dialog:

```
binding.btnRight.setOnClickListener(v -> {
    NavHostFragment navHostFragment = (NavHostFragment) requireActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.container);
    if (navHostFragment != null) {
        NavController navController = navHostFragment.getNavController();
        NavBackStackEntry navBackStackEntry = navController.getPreviousBackStackEntry();
        if (navBackStackEntry != null) {
            SavedStateHandle savedStateHandle = navBackStackEntry.getSavedStateHandle();
            savedStateHandle.set(Const.DIALOG_BTN_DATA, "btn_right");
        }
        navController.navigateUp();
    }
});
```

I need to show DialogFragment when another DialogFragment result received, but app crashes in statement `navController2.navigate(MyFragmentDirections.actionMyFragmentToMessageDialog...` and I get the below error:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Navigation action/destination com.example.app:id/action_myFragment_to_messageDialog cannot be found from the current destination
```

Can anyone help me to solve the problem and show DialogFragment in navBackStackEntry observer result of another DialogFragment using NavigationComponent?

Comment: Did you read the [Considerations when using dialog destinations](https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-programmatic#additional_considerations)? It, literally word for word, explains exactly what is happening with this case and the code that works for this case. Is there a reason you aren't following that guide?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue is not related to usage of `navController`. You can find its definition in [Navigation Component documents](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/navigation/NavController).

So I avoid to describe them and want to focus on your code.

**Action** `X` to `Y` means you want navigate to `Y` only from `X`. In other words the last entry/destination in back-stack must be `X`.

#### 1.

In your case when `MyFragment` is shown, the back-stack is like:

```
[ MyFragment ]
```

and when you call `getSavedStateHandle()` and start observing its `savedState` means you're obsrving `MyFragment`'s savedState.

#### 2.

When you want to launch dialog with `"My Message 1"` in button click listener, back-stack is still:

```
[ MyFragment ]
```

and after launching the dialog will be like:

```
[ MyFragment, MessageDialog ]
```

So when you `getPreviousBackStackEntry` in dialog, it refers to `MyFragment` and successfully `set(Const.DIALOG_BTN_DATA, "btn_right")` on `MyFragment`'s savedState.

At this time the observer in `MyFragment` will be triggered and try to launch dialog via `actionMyFragmentToMessageDialog` with `"My Message 2"`.

This action is from `MyFragment` to `MessageDialog` but the latest entry in back-stack is `MessageDialog` (Not MyFragment). BOOOM

and `navController.navigateUp()` will never invoke to pop dialog :D

---

> show DialogFragment in navBackStackEntry observer result of another DialogFragment using NavigationComponent?

Your issue comes from restriction of local actions. So you should navigate by `destination-id`s or `deeplink`s or better one is `GlobalActions` that provide safe-arg facilities.

I suggest global actions in this situation:

```xml
<action
    android:id="@+id/action_global_messageDialog"
    app:destination="@id/messageDialog" />
```

```
navController2.navigate(
    MyGraphDirections.actionGlobalMessageDialog(
        false,
        R.drawable.ic_success,
        "My Message 2"
        R.string.yes,
        R.string.no,
        R.drawable.circle_red
    ));
```

Comment: Thanks for your very detailed explanation. And how to solve it?

Comment: @AlirezaNoorali You just talked about a crash. Didn't write about your demands. Update the question. I'll check it again

Comment: @AlirezaNoorali My answer has been updated